# Grease pencil go straight into draw mode by pressing "B" with a Grease Pencil object selected

Tags: shortcut, grease-pencil

If I have a grease pencil object selected, I want to immediately go to draw mode by pressing <kbd>B</kbd>. I can do this by setting "Object.mode_set" to <kbd>B</kbd> under the Grease Pencil category:

[image]

However, with this set, I cannot switch to the draw tool using <kbd>B</kbd> like I am used to in Krita & Photoshop. Is there a way to solve this key conflict?

Answer (score 0):

You have set a new key building in the *Grease pencil (global)* group. This group basically means that this hotkeys is used in Grease pencil globally - in all tools and in all Grease pencil modes (paint, edit, sculpt) but not in object mode. Thats means that to launch this command you have to be in one of Grease pencil modes, but you are in Object mode, so that this command is ignored.

So that you have to use suitable keymap group.

- *3D View* ⇾ *3D View (Global)* is good for that, key building from this group will be executed in every mode including Grease pencil edit mode or pencil sculpt mode
- *3D View* ⇾ *Object Mode* ⇾ *Object Mode (Global)* also is good, but the difference that it will be  executed only in object mode, in
  Grease pencil edit mode or pencil sculpt mode it will not work.

Comment: Ì have already disabled all of those. And it's still not giving me what I am looking for. If I disable the "object.mode_set" operator, then it is switching like I want it to, so it seems like I cannot get into Grease Pencil draw mode using B and switch tools to the draw brush using B.

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently for my 3D/2D Keymap just because of this post, and it's actually very simple to do.

Set Grease Pencil Draw Mode as the B hotkey in *3D View > Object Non-modal*, and then in *Grease Pencil > Paint Mode*, right click the *Draw Brush Tool*, and set it to the <kbd>B</kbd> hotkey.